# Elementary Properties of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Homework Problem from Group Theory:
Prove the following:
For any cyclic group of order *n*, there are elements of order *k*, for every integer, *k*, which divides *n*.

What I have so far..

Take G as a cyclic group generated by *a*. >>>> G=, *a*^(*n*)=e, where e is the indentity.
I know that if G is indeed cyclic, it must be generated by a single element, *a*.  So, if another element, say *b*, of order *k* is in the group, it must be some multiple of *n*.

ord(*b*)=*k*

ord(*a*)=*n*

We are given that *k* divides *n*, which I know is the key here, but I am unsure how to start this.
I have tried

*a*^(*n*)=(*b*^(*n*))^*k*
which is then equal to 
e=e^*k*, which is simply e.
I feel like I'm on the right track, but am missing something here.

Comment: Try $\;G=\langle a\rangle\;\;and\;\;n=kd\implies ord(a^{n/d})=k\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it. Since $k | n$, there exists an $l$ for which $kl = n$. Now define an element by
$$h = g^l$$
Then we have
$$h^k = (g^l)^k = g^{lk} = g^n = e$$

so the order of $h$ is at most $k$. The order is at least $k$, and I'll leave that for you to show. So $h$ is the desired element.

Comment: Great! I knew there was something else I needed! Thank you!